# Multiple results - Need only the latest price

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the latest price for some items

This is my query:

```
 SELECT 
 MAX("POPORH1"."DATE") as "PO DATE",
 "ICSHEH"."DOCNUM", 
 "ICSHEH"."TRANSDATE", 
 "ICSHEH"."FISCYEAR", 
 "ICSHEH"."FISCPERIOD", 
 "ICSHEH"."REFERENCE", 
 "ICSHED"."ITEMNO", 
 "ICSHED"."ITEMDESC", 
 "ICSHED"."LOCATION", 
 "ICSHED"."QUANTITY", 
 "ICSHED"."UNIT", 
 "POPORL"."UNITCOST"

 FROM   (("CABDAT"."dbo"."ICSHEH" "ICSHEH" 
 INNER JOIN 
 "CABDAT"."dbo"."ICSHED" "ICSHED" ON "ICSHEH"."SEQUENCENO"="ICSHED"."SEQUENCENO") 
 INNER JOIN "CABDAT"."dbo"."POPORL" "POPORL" ON "ICSHED"."ITEMNO"="POPORL"."ITEMNO") 
 INNER JOIN "CABDAT"."dbo"."POPORH1" "POPORH1" ON "POPORL"."PORHSEQ"="POPORH1"."PORHSEQ"
 WHERE  "ICSHED"."SEQUENCENO"=55873
 group by
 "ICSHEH"."DOCNUM", 
 "ICSHEH"."TRANSDATE", 
 "ICSHEH"."FISCYEAR", 
 "ICSHEH"."FISCPERIOD", 
 "ICSHEH"."REFERENCE", 
 "ICSHED"."ITEMNO", 
 "ICSHED"."ITEMDESC", 
 "ICSHED"."LOCATION", 
 "ICSHED"."QUANTITY", 
 "ICSHED"."UNIT", 
 "POPORL"."UNITCOST"
```

This query returns multiple results

These are the results:

```
"PODATE"='20180405' "ITEMNO"='2944'  "UNITCOST"='0.266750'
"PODATE"='20180405' "ITEMNO"='2946'  "UNITCOST"='0.266750'
"PODATE"='20170208' "ITEMNO"='2944'  "UNITCOST"='0.250780'
"PODATE"='20170208' "ITEMNO"='2944'  "UNITCOST"='0.250780'
"PODATE"='20170208' "ITEMNO"='2946'  "UNITCOST"='0.250780'
"PODATE"='20170208' "ITEMNO"='2946'  "UNITCOST"='0.250780'
```

I need to have only 
"PODATE"='20180405' "ITEMNO"='2944'  "UNITCOST"='0.266750'
"PODATE"='20180405' "ITEMNO"='2946'  "UNITCOST"='0.266750'

I am learning SQL, so please be patient with my ignorance...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You just need `row_number()`.

```
 WITH cte as (
     SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "ITEMNO" ORDER BY  "PODATE" DESC) as rn
     FROM "ICSHED"  -- or join tables
     WHERE "ICSHED"."SEQUENCENO"=55873
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM cte where rn = 1
```

Or if you only need the highest value without any grouping can use `TOP 1`

```
 SELECT TOP 1 *
 FROM "ICSHED"  -- or join tables
 WHERE "ICSHED"."SEQUENCENO"=55873
 ORDER  "PODATE" DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding, you want top 2 rows with recent date. so I try this,

```
  select top 2 * from yourtable order by dateCol desc
```